# confused about using flutter_screenutil package

Tags: flutter, user-interface, responsive-design, flutter-packages

I have a question about using [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) package.

The package has two methods for setting `width` and `height`.

1. First one when using `ScreenUtil().setWidth(540)` or `ScreenUtil().setHeight(540)`
2. when using extensions like `540.w` or `540.h`

I am confused about which method should I use?

Answer (score 1):

If your dart **sdk>=2.6**, you can use extension functions:

example:

instead of :

```
Container(
  width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(50),
  height:ScreenUtil().setHeight(200),
)
```

you can use it like this:

```
Container(
  width: 50.w,
  height:200.h
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any one method , both methods will give you same result

```
Container(
  width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(540),
  height:ScreenUtil().setHeight(540),
)

Container(
  width: 540.w,
  height:540.h,
)
```